# Why is this try/except loop exiting on errors?

Tags: python, try-except

I have a script that collects Reddit comments. It pulls from a csv file with a list of links in it. Some of the links are dead and I get 404/403/etc errors. The code below will correctly identify them and skip, but it then exits the loop and completes the process of making the csv file without continuing onto the next link.

```
import praw
import pprint
import csv
import os
import pandas as pd
from collections import namedtuple
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path

def scrape_comments(reddit_api, csv_file, dest):
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    data = []
    try:
        for pid in df.id:
            # post_comment = []
            submission = reddit_api.submission(id=pid)
            submission.comments.replace_more(limit=None)
            for comment in submission.comments.list():
                # post_comment.append(comment.body)
                data.append((pid, comment.id, comment.parent_id, comment.body, comment.link_id,comment.author, comment.score, comment.created_utc, comment.subreddit))
            # data.append((pid, ";".join(post_comment)))
    except:
        print ("Error! Skip the Current subreddit")
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["post_id", "comment_id", "comment_parent_id", "comment_body", "comment_link_id","comment_author", "comment_score","comment_created","comment_subreddit"]) # append tuple
    df.to_csv(dest, index=False, encoding='utf-8')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    reddit_api = praw.Reddit(
        client_id="####",
        client_secret="####",
        user_agent="####",
        username="####",
        password="####"
    )
    # reddit_api = init_praw(client_id, client_secret, user_agent, username, password)
    csv_file = "####"
    dest_dir = "####"
    dest_name = "reddits_comments.csv"
    Path(dest_dir).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    dest = os.path.join(dest_dir, dest_name)
    scrape_comments(reddit_api, csv_file, dest)
```

Comment: It could be that the posts you had linked were deleted, or that they are in a restricted subreddit that does not allow for this process to function. i.e. Blocked by Reddit. It could be, and most likely is, a mix of both.

Comment: Make a narrower `try..except` block…?! Don't put it around the entire loop, but around the individual function call that may fail, so the rest of the loop can continue.

Comment: I know why they are skipping, but the list is 75,000 posts long so I am not going to go through it realistically. I just want it to stop exiting and just move onto the next one.

Comment: To make the above comment more clear - get the `try` , `except` inside the `for` loop and also better to handle exceptions separately. just a blanket `except` for all exceptions ma not be a good idea.

Comment: put the `try` within the `for` loop, not the other way around.

Comment: Put the try except inside the for loop. Currently, with your except block outside of the for loop, any exception handling will exit the for loop.

Comment: Has anyone suggested putting the `try..except` inside the `for` loop yet?

Comment: To clarify other comments, when an exception is raised, the remainder of the `try` block will be skipped and control flow will jump to the `except` block.  Since your `try ... except` contains the *entire* loop, you end up skipping further iterations and jumping outside of the loop.

Comment: The exception being raised exits the loop. Catching the exception *outside* the loop doesn't change that; control does not resume at the point where the exception was originally raised, but where it is *caught*. (Imagine if you caught an exception raised by a function called by a function called by a function *you* called. Would you be surprised if execution resumed deep in the call stack?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the `try/except` around a smaller portion of your code, as said in the comments.  Here's an illustration of that:

```
def scrape_comments(reddit_api, csv_file, dest):
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    data = []
    for pid in df.id:
        try:
            # post_comment = []
            submission = reddit_api.submission(id=pid)
            submission.comments.replace_more(limit=None)
            for comment in submission.comments.list():
                # post_comment.append(comment.body)
                data.append((pid, comment.id, comment.parent_id, comment.body, comment.link_id,comment.author, comment.score, comment.created_utc, comment.subreddit))
            # data.append((pid, ";".join(post_comment)))
        except Exception:
            print ("Error! Skip the Current subreddit")
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["post_id", "comment_id", "comment_parent_id", "comment_body", "comment_link_id","comment_author", "comment_score","comment_created","comment_subreddit"]) # append tuple
    df.to_csv(dest, index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```